# How to define global constant char pointer in C and redefine poiting value throughout files

Tags: c, pointers, compilation, global

i'm quite new in C, what i'm trying to do is define a pointer with a constant address, this is my attempt in testHeader.h:

```
char const *MY_VAR_P = (char * const)(0x4fffff);
extern char MYVAR;
```

then in the global of test.c (but i got in mind to reuse the same pointer with same address in other .c files...):

```
#include "testHeader.h"

char MYVAR = '0'; 
*MY_VAR_P = MYVAR;
```

and this is the error:

```
test.c:33: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `MY_VAR_P'
test.c:33: conflicting types for `MY_VAR_P'
test.h:2: previous declaration of `MY_VAR_P'
test.c:33: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
test.c:33: initializer element is not constant
```

I really don't understand...please someone can help me?

thanks!

Comment: change to `char * const MY_VAR_P = (char * const)(0x4fffff);` and `*MY_VAR_P = MYVAR;` move to inside of function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems with that line:

- `MY_VAR_P` has type *pointer to constant char*. You cannot modify what `MY_VAR_P` points to through that pointer. Maybe you meant for that variable to be a *const pointer to char*?

  ```
  char * const MY_VAR_P = ...;
  ```
- You can't run code outside functions. The assignment `*MY_VAR_P = foo` need to go inside your main, or some other function. (The other to places where you use `=` are not assignments, they are initializations.)

Comment: Yes, i want a fixed, actually constant, address for my pointer. But the variabile it refers has to be dynamic...
So how do i have to write?
Ok for the next assignment...

Comment: I put that in my answer already - `char * const`. The position of const is important. `const char *` and `char const *` mean (non-const) pointer to const data. `char * const` means const pointer to non-const data. Read from right to left.